# How do I use an SSH File Transfer Protocol client (Cyberduck) through two ssh "points"

Tags: ssh, sftp, cyberduck

I am trying to log in to my computer at work through cyberduck.

I can ssh into the computer just fine but I must first SSH into the central system, then ssh from there into my computer.

Is there a way to allow Cyberduck to ssh into my work computer, i.e. ssh twice at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. PuTTY to set up the port forwarding, also called an SSH tunneling (for purposes such as yours).

See https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding

Alternatively you can use an SFTP client that supports this natively, e.g. [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/).
There's a guide for this here:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel

Note that aside from instructions, how to do this using WinSCP native tunneling functionality (section *[Section up tunnel in WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_winscp)*), the guide also shows, how to tunnel WinSCP via PuTTY (section *[Section up tunnel using PuTTY for SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty)*). So if you insist on using Cyberduck, you can just replace WinSCP with Cyberduck in the guide.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure local port forwarding. With it, localhost's socket will be forwarded to your work computer so middle SSH server will work as proxy.

Comment: Oh cool! I hate to be a bother, but could you point me to the right direction to get started with local port forwarding? very unfamiliar with it.